# How can I loop through the drop down menu on this page to web-scrape each products' specs and price?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hi I am relatively new to Python and Web-scraping. I am trying to scrape the data from each product option in the drop down menu on this page (https://www.jmesales.com/kuriyama-3-4-in-brass-quick-couplings/). I believe the page does not use JavaScript and I would rather just use requests and BeautifulSoup as opposed to a webdriver. I have code that can get me the name and attribute value of each option but I am unsure how to access the pricing and spec data that is associated with each option. This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.jmesales.com/kuriyama-3-4-in-brass-quick-couplings/'

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

options = [item['value'] for item in soup.select('#attribute_select_42800 option')]

for option in options:
    print(option)
```

I would like to access the price and associated data with each option. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.jmesales.com/kuriyama-3-4-in-brass-quick-couplings/'
s = requests.Session()
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
res = s.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

options = [[item['value'], name.text] for item, name in zip(soup.select('#attribute_select_42800 option'), soup.select('#attribute_select_42800 option'))]



id = soup.select_one('input[name^="product_id"]').get('value')

for option in options[1:]:
    item_num, item_name = option
    data = {'action': 'add', 'attribute[42800]': item_num, 'product_id': id, 'qty[]': '1'}
    product = s.post('https://www.jmesales.com/remote/v1/product-attributes/53564', data=data).json()
    price = product['data']['price']['without_tax']['formatted']

    print(f'Item name: {item_name} Item price: {price}')
```

prints:

```
Item name: Part A Female NPT x Male Adapter Item price: $6.30
Item name: Part B Female Coupler x Male NPT Item price: $13.80
Item name: Part C Female Coupler x Hose Shank Item price: $11.50
Item name: Part D Female Coupler x Female NPT Item price: $12.80
Item name: Part E Male Adapter x Hose Shank Item price: $8.50
Item name: Part F Male NPT x Male Adapter Item price: $7.30
Item name: Dust Cap Item price: $11.00
Item name: Dust Plug Item price: $8.10
```

The above code only take from the specific url you had as example this can parse multi urls:

```
url = 'https://www.jmesales.com/dixon-brass-female-ght-x-female-npt-adapter-lead-free/'
s = requests.Session()
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
res = s.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

attrid = re.findall('\[([\d]+)\]', soup.select_one('.form-select.form-select--small').get('name'))[0]

options = [[item['value'], name.text] for item, name in zip(soup.select(f'#attribute_select_{attrid} option'), soup.select(f'#attribute_select_{attrid} option'))]


id = soup.select_one('input[name^="product_id"]').get('value')

for option in options[1:]:
    item_num, item_name = option
    data = {'action': 'add', f'attribute[{attrid}]': item_num, 'product_id': id, 'qty[]': '1'}
    product = s.post(f'https://www.jmesales.com/remote/v1/product-attributes/{id}', data=data).json()
    price = product['data']['price']['without_tax']['formatted']

    print(f'Item name: {item_name} Item price: {price}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will help:

```
from pyautogui import typewrite

amount_of_options = 4 # Amount of options in the menu
typewrite(['enter']) # Click on the dropdown menu

for i in range(amount_of_options):
    typewrite(['tab']) # Each tab will navigate to the next option in the menu
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm sorry I'm not very knowledgeable on this. How do I use this to get to the data that I am after?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to what you have been looking for, but for webscraping I recommend using selenium.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

It's as simple as, open the browser and you can do whatever you want. What I would do is look for the xpaths and look for a pattern to iterate.

Comment: This is indeed an answer.